# How to find that where and how a OBJECT is used in the application?

Tags: object, field-dependencies

I have a custom object whose records are created via some other process. It cannot be created directly since it does not have a TAB created. There is no trigger on the object and I cannot find any of the class which is using this object.

I have searched online but did not find any proper approach to do it. I do not have eclipse so setting it up and then getting all the metadata is a lot of work. I tried creating a change set and adding that object to check dependencies but there also I did not get anything.

I am avoiding the approach of trying deleting the object to check dependency since I am afraid that if by mistake it gets deleted then I don't know where all it was used.

Is there any other approach to get this ?

Thanks! Ruchi

Comment: If that object is referenced somewhere then it won't be deleted.

Comment: You can create a Sandbox (if not already created) and check there.

Comment: @TusharSharma :  I tried it in sandbox  and got to know the class . Thanks!

Comment: There is an app called metadata search on appexchange. You can install it and search for the object API name. I'm not the creator of the app.